# How to avoid data copy in NDIS filter driver

Tags: ndis

I am working on a NDIS filter driver which actually copies data from NET_BUFFERs to driver allocated buffers in the Send path and push these driver allocated buffers into a internal queue. Later on, the data is copied again from these driver allocated buffers in the queue to IRP buffers. I want to avoid this copy of data.

In Linux, we can create a clone of skbuff and the cloned skbuff can be queued for later use. Is there a similar option available in Windows as well? If there a way to clone the NET_BUFFER, we can simply avoid the first copy that is happening from NET_BUFFER to driver allocated memory buffers.

If there exists a way to achieve zero copy from the NetBufferLists to IRP buffers, then it would really be an ideal solution. It would be really helpful if someone can suggest a better solution to avoid the copies in the send path.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Meaning the most optimized way of sending the packet content to user process for processing.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear to me why you need to copy the NB (NET_BUFFER) at all.  If you plan to enqueue the NB for processing on a different thread, you can do that with the original NB — no need to copy anything.

The only reason here that you'd need to copy the payload is if you plan to hang onto the buffer for a while (say, more than 1000ms).  At a high level, the payload associated with an NB belongs to the application.  NDIS permits you to queue the NB, do some processing, drop it, modify it, etc.  But (depending on socket options) the application may be stuck until its buffer is completed back to it.  So you cannot hang onto the original NB or its payload *indefinitely*.  If you're going to do something that takes a long time then you should allocate a deep copy of all the datastructures you need (the NBL, the NB, the MDL, and the payload buffer) and return the originals back to the application.

If you're stuffing the packet payload into an IRP so that a usermode process can contemplate the payload, then you really do need 1 copy.  The reason is that kernel can't trust any usermode process to do anything within a particular time budget.  Imagine, for example, that the system is going to hibernate.  The kernel duly suspends all usermode processes, then waits for each device to go a low power state.  But the network card can't go to low power, because the datapath won't pause because some packet is stuck in your filter driver, waiting for the (now suspended) usermode process to reply.  Thus, you protect yourself by detaching the IO to usermode with the IO over the network device: make a copy.

But if all you're doing is shipping the packet off to another kernel device that does (say) encryption, then you can assume that the encryption device assures a reasonable time budget, so it may be safe to give the original packet payload to it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I really need to copy the payload in NB and pass it on to a user mode process calling read. Right now, in the SendNetBufferLists(), the payload in NB is copied to an intermediate buffer allocated by the driver and this intermediate buffer is added to a queue. In the dispatch (read) routine, the intermediate buffer is removed from the queue and copied to the IRP buffer. I want to copy the payload directly from NB to IRP buffer which should be possible if we can put NB in a queue. It would save one copy. It would be really helpful if you can suggest a way to do that.